# How to wait for an activity to complete from java class before proceeding?

Tags: android

I have a plane java class which accepts an Activity in constructor. Now with that activity I am starting another activity for some permissions. Now I want to wait for this activity to complete before proceeding next.

```
public final class Test{
@NonNull
private final Activity activity;

public Test(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void initialize() {
    try {
        if(isEnabled) {
            this.activity.startActivity(new Intent(this.activity, CheckPermissionsActivity.class));
        }

FileUtils.readFile(Constants.XX+ Constants.YY);

}
```

I want to make this readFile method run after the CheckPermissionsActivity is complete. How to make the main thread wait?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a separate class for permission checking then do something like this. 
NOTE: I'm only explaining the basic concept. do the changes according to your requirements.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckPermissionsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);//101=requestCode

        // write this according to your requirements in CheckPermissionsActivity 
          Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("result", mString);
            if (mString.length() > 2) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
            } else {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, i);
            }
            finish();


        // in your main activity use this callback and use in your Test class
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                    if (requestCode == 101 && data != null) {
            // write your code here
            }
}
```

Comment: Since this (Test class) is not a activity, onActivityResult is not getting hit. It would work only when we call an activity from another activity. The calling activity is different and I cant use it. :(

Comment: you can pass the activity reference while initializing Test object inside your Activity class. once you will get the callback in your Activity notify Test class using its object.

Comment: I don't have the access to the Activity class. I am working on sdk. where they just pass the activity.

Comment: as of now, you can ask the user to pass result like this. Test.activityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
 I'm checking for you the best way.

Comment: please take this class as a reference, https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission/blob/master/tedpermission/src/main/java/com/gun0912/tedpermission/TedPermissionActivity.java
or the above comment. extend your Test class with Activity.